# Is there a method to commit changes to a file using the library org.eclipse.egit.github.core. I could not find a way to do it?

Tags: github, egit

I am using the egit-github library in my java application. My use cases involve fetching a file from a repository, editing the content and committing it back to repository. 
I know that github v3 apis provides contents endpoint (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-or-update-a-file), to edit and update a file. But I could not find relevant method in egit-github library.